# Bootstrap React Jumbotron Background Image

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to get a background image onto a jumbotron in Bootstrap React? I've tried using style sheets and using inline styles (camelCase) but neither have worked. As of now I have this currently on my css stylesheet. I can get the image to appear in chrome dev tools but Bootstrap React must be overriding the background color in some fashion but I'm not sure how. Here is the code I have on the stylesheet:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("https://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/shady-forest.jpg")!important;
 }
```

And here is the code I have for the component:

```
<>
<Jumbotron fluid>
<Container>
<h1>Fluid jumbotron</h1>
<p>
  This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of
  its parent.
</p>
</Container>
</Jumbotron>
</>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's late but the style attribute is "backgroundImage" and you can call it like:

```
<Jumbotron fluid style={{backgroundImage: `url(...)`}}>
```